# Is it possible to make a shortcut for a bash command that will also include variables?

Tags: linux, bash

For example, is it possible to make shortcut for

`tar cf - /VARIABLE_1 -P | pv -s $(du -sb /VARIABLE_1 | awk '{print $1}') | gzip > VARIABLE_2.tar.gz`

such that one could simply type `tarpb VARIABLE_1 VARIABLE_2` ? Or is it only possible via scripting?

Answer (score 1):

There is a middle way, using functions. In your `.bashrc`, you could define a function to do this:

```
tarbp() {
  input=$1
  output=$2
  tar cf - /"${input}" -P | pv -s "$(du -sb /"${input}" | awk '{print $1}')" | gzip > "${output}".tar.gz
}
```

`$1` and `$2` are the first and second parameter passed to the function.

After restarting your shell (or reloading your `.bashrc`), you can use the function like a regular command:

```
tarbp input output
```

*(Ubuntu even does bash completion on this)*